# Show that $V = \{x \in \text{(Real numbers)}^{2,2};AX=X^TA^T\}$ is a vector space, solution verification

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

$V = \{X \in \text{(Real numbers)}^{2,2};AX=X^TA^T\}$ is a vector space?

For addition:$$A_1X+A_2X = (A_1+A_2)X=X^T(A_1+A_2)^T$$
For multiplication with scalar:
$$AX\alpha=(A\alpha)X=X^T(A\alpha)^T$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Is $V$ the set of all $x, X$ or $A$?

Comment: @TrevorGunn It was meant to be X as a matrix

Comment: So why $A_1$ and $A_2$ and not $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Comment: I thought that that is how we show it ? @TrevorGunn, the same as for polynomials where we change the coefficients, am I wrong ?